# Change color in beamer template

Tags: beamer, color

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\definecolor{blub}{RGB}{51,51,178} 
\definecolor{blub2}{RGB}{173,173,224} 
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Approximation of coupler potential}
%\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=blub}
%\setbeamercolor{block body}{use=structure,bg=white}
        \begin{block}{ asd}
asdasdasd
            \end{block}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want to change the block title background color to blub and the block title text color to white.

If i use the command

```
%\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=blub}
```

The titel is good, however the block content color is also changed i do not understand why and how can i fix this. I want to keep the old colors, which i think is blub2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Boadilla` theme internally loads the `rose` color theme, in which the colors of the block title and block body are defined as follows:

```
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=structure.fg!20!bg}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!50!bg}
```

Since the `block body` background color is defined as `block title.bg!50!bg` it depends on the background color of the `block title` which is why `block body` changes upon redefining the `block title` color. To overcome this and only change the colors of `block title` while keeping `block body` as before, you can use the following:

```
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=blub}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=structure.fg!20!bg!50!bg}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\definecolor{blub}{RGB}{51,51,178} 

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=blub}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=structure.fg!20!bg!50!bg}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Approximation of coupler potential}
    \begin{block}{ asd}
        asdasdasd
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the tex wizard has spoken